# Test whether both username and password fields are empty

Tags: java, junit, assertions

```
@Test
public void loginWithEmptyFields() throws InterruptedException {
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Tu Log In / Register")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_username")).sendKeys("");
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    driver.findElement(By.className("loginButtonMain")).click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}
```

Assert code should check whether both username and password fields are empty, if the fields are empty the login button is disabled and should get the title the page which is 'Login - Tu Clothing'.

However the below code is not working please help!

```
boolean actualEmptyLoginButton = 
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".loginButtonMain")).isEnabled();
Assert.assertTrue(actualEmptyLoginButton, "Login Button is not displayed");

String actualEmptyLoginTitle = driver.getTitle();
Assert.assertEquals("Login | Tu clothing", actualEmptyLoginTitle);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, your title must be minimal to help people to understand your question specifically, and improved your tag section so your question can reach to the desired criteria.

Comment: Can you specify exactly what your question is?

Comment: I want the assert code to get the title of the page as there is no error message that appears when the fields are empty so when the login button is clicked the button is disabled. Therefore I would like the code to get the title of the page

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you are using Selenium to verify that the title of your login button has changed, after the fields for username and password are cleared.

It looks like some JavaScript is executed, when the content of the text field is cleared.

So I recommend to use a WebDriver for a real browser (e.g. Firefox). Also avoid Thread.sleep(). Better use an explicit wait for the condition, see more at the Selenium documentation for [explicit and implicit waits](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).